# How to get innerHTML from a div?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, innerhtml

I need to save the innerHTML of a div and store it in a cookie. Here is my basic code.

```
//The div-saving function
function addStatus(sName){
    getElement("bottomDiv").innerHTML += sName + "<br>";
    document.cookie="status=" + sName + "<br>";
}

//The button clicking function
function clk(){
    num++;
    document.cookie = "num=" + num;
    switch(num){
        case 25:
            addStatus("25: Alright! Let the games begin!");
        break;
        case 50:
            addStatus("50: Woah! Getting into the high numbers!");
        break;
    }
}
```

What ends up happening is only the last achieved status gets saved. I need to know how to get the innerHTML of the div instead. Thank you.

Comment: does your div have a class or id?

Comment: Please change the line:

document.cookie = "status"+document.getElementById("bottomDiv").innerHTML+"</br>"

Comment: Paste your html code here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: document.cookie="status=" + document.getElementById("bottomDiv").innerHTML+ "<br>";

Comment: Here it is the link for jsfiddle. For some reason some stuff is broken dont know why it works perfectly on my local server. http://jsfiddle.net/Txdt4/

Answer (score 6):

Try this..

```
 var div= document.getElementById("bottomDiv").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var holder = document.getElementById("bottomDiv").innerHTML;
```

The above will get the innerHTML value and assign it to the variable.  Also there is no built in function `getElement` , you can use `getElementById`, there are other variations as well.

Comment: I know there is no built in function getElement. I forget to mention I made that function.