# Javascript targeting the parent div from a string of text

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <span class="mySpan">SAMPLE TEXT A</span>
    <span class="mySpan">SAMPLE TEXT B</span>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to get the right javascript to hide "myDiv" if the text in "mySpan" is "SAMPLE TEXT A".

Comment: Please show us the JavaScript that you tried to do that, and describe how exactly it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190848/how-to-get-innerhtml-from-a-div

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then share a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.
Then, click to `edit` your question so that we may help.

Comment: var x = document.getElementByClassName(' mySpan:contains("SAMPLE TEXT A") ');
$(x).parents(':eq(1)').css( 'display:none' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow like this (you will not see anything, because `<div class="myDiv">` is hidden already):

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('mySpan')

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if(spans[i].innerHTML === 'SAMPLE TEXT A') spans[i].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <span class="mySpan">SAMPLE TEXT A</span>
    <span class="mySpan">SAMPLE TEXT B</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

*"What is the significance of the 'for' statement?"*

`document.getElementsByClassName('mySpan')` will select **ALL** elements with class `mySpan`, think about it as an array. Then i iterate through all selected `span`'s and finding the case, where `innerHTML` is equal to our specific string.

*"In the if statement, how would I specify just the parent div and not every element with class "myDiv"? There are other elements on the page with that class."*

If so, you need to use `parentElement` (I have updated my answer with needed row).

Comment: Okay I see. This is working for me. I'm not experienced with javascript and I imagine it might have been the mix of jQuery that's throwing me off. What is the significance of the 'for' statement?

Comment: In the if statement, how would I specify just the parent div and not every element with class "myDiv"? There are other elements on the page with that class.

Comment: @John, I have updated the answer with useful (I hope) info for you.

Comment: Yes okay that worked. I tried the same thing but I was leaving out the [i] just before .parentElement. Thank you!

Comment: If it's really helpful, please, accept my answer =)